# Dynamic Views Pages - How to add in meta tags to these generated pages?

Tags: theming, views, meta-tags

I have 1000s of dynamically generated views pages using contentual filters. I want to be able to take certain keywords from these generated pages and add them to the on page meta tags. Currently I do not have any metatags on these pages. Is there a module that can add such a functionality that can inject it into a view?

If there is no such module, do you think the best way would be to create a custom tpl just for these dynamic pages and output these keywords on the html.tpl.php template?

Answer (score 2):

The [metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) comes with 'metatag views'. Enabling this module you with have a metatag settings on the metatag config page (admin/config/search/metatags).

I am not sure what meta tags you are referring to but I will give you an example.

I am using the view that overrides the default taxonomy term pages. To set the description meta tag for this view I put '[view:description][current-page:url:args:value:1]' into the metatag setting for views.

If you are worried about the keyword metatag I would not bother as they ont seem  to impact seo anymore, and I don't know of an easy way to set this dynamically for views.

You may also want to check out the [metatag views overview module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag_views_overview) which has a confusing description but may help you.

Also, take a look in the file '[metatag.api.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/metatag/tree/metatag.api.php)' in the metatag module for something that you could use.